# find_package with specified version in configuration script name

Tags: c++, cmake, mongo-c-driver

I need to use mangrove (mongo ODM lib over mongo-c-driver and mongo-cxx-driver) and included this into my project as CMake ExternalProject_Add command, with a dependency on mongo-c-driver/mongo-cxx-driver

mongocxx generates CMake configuration scripts with a names like :

> libmongocxx-config.cmake
>
> libmongocxx-config-version.cmake

and no issues to find these by mangrove with that script:

```
set(LIBMONGOCXX_REQUIRED_VERSION 3.1.3)
set(LIBMONGOCXX_REQUIRED_ABI_VERSION v_noabi)
find_package(libmongocxx ${LIBMONGOCXX_REQUIRED_VERSION} REQUIRED)
```

However mongo-c-driver generates those scripts with a name which incudes ABI version into file names.

> libmongoc-1.0-config.cmake
>
> libmongoc-1.0-config-version.cmake

and similar CMake code:

```
set(LIBMONGOC_REQUIRED_VERSION 1.7.0)
set(LIBMONGOC_REQUIRED_ABI_VERSION 1.0)
find_package(LibMongoC ${LIBMONGOC_REQUIRED_VERSION} REQUIRED)
```

can't find out the scripts.

Of course, if I manually remove the version from file names, it can find those files, but I'd like to fix the problem in a script and on mangove side.

So the question about CMake techniques :

Is there an ability to specify the version of package which will automatically used by (inside CMake scripts names) `find_package` command to look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) documentation, the version is embedded inside the `libmongocxx-config-version.cmake` file.

This means that if you want to get the package `libmongoc-1.0-config.cmake`, you should use:

```
find_package(libmongoc-1.0 ${LIBMONGOC_REQUIRED_VERSION} REQUIRED)
```